# PyQt TabWidget extra pixel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have an app where I'm subclassing `QTabBar` and customising it, and then setting it in `QTabWidget`. I'm getting a coloured pixel appearing next to last tab when there is more than 1 tab.

See below for a minimum reproducible example (I have not subclassed `QTabBar` here, just to keep things simple)

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication
    ,QMainWindow
    ,QTabWidget
    ,QWidget
    ,QTabBar
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabWidget = TabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

class TabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._tabBar = QTabBar() #This is subclassed in the actual app
        self.setTabBar(self._tabBar)
        
        self.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab 1")
        self.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab 2")
        
        # The below also produces the extra pixel
        #self._tabBar.addTab("Tab 1")
        #self._tabBar.addTab("Tab 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

It's hard to see, but at the bottom right corner of "Tab 2", there is a coloured pixel there. Adding the tabs either via `QTabWidget.addTab()` or `QTabBar.addTab()` seems to produce the same thing. However, it only appears when there's more than 1 tab.

This doesn't seem to happen if I don't manually set the tab bar via `self.setTabBar(self._tabBar)`

i.e. the below code doesn't produce the pixel

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication
    ,QMainWindow
    ,QTabWidget
    ,QWidget
    ,QTabBar
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabWidget = TabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

class TabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #self._tabBar = QTabBar(self) #This is subclassed in the actual app
        #self.setTabBar(self._tabBar)
        
        self.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab 1")
        self.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab 2")
        
        # The below also produces the extra pixel
        #self._tabBar.addTab("Tab 1")
        #self._tabBar.addTab("Tab 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**EDIT:**

Curiously, on PyQt5, I get the below

[image]

`PyQt6.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR` is 6.4.0

`PyQt5.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR` is 5.9.7

I'm running this via an IPython console on Windows 11.

Comment: Are you saying that the code above (which does *not* subclass QTabBar) **does** reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, the code snippet produces the issue for me (the screenshot was taken from running the code snippet)

Comment: Try using `self.tabBar = QTabBar(self)`. (note that, since [`tabBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabBar) is an existing function, you should not overwrite it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this still produces the same result it seems

Comment: And if you don't use `setTabBar()` this doesn't happen?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, let me update the question

Comment: It *could* be a bug. Does this happen for both PyQt5 and 6? Can you specify the Qt (`QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`) and OS? Also, are you running this from a venv, an IDE or directly from terminal/prompt/file browser? Does the output of the terminal/prompt show anything relevant?

Comment: I've just tried PyQt5 (see the updated question for a screenshot and details about versions), it seems like in PyQt5 the inactive tabs are underlined, which extends beyond the tab by a pixel or two, which may be causing the artifact in PyQt6?

Comment: They are not just "underlined", that's the way tabs are highlighted or put "into the background" to show whether they're selected or not. It's called "skeumorphism", meaning that the visual representation resembles the aspect and behavior of physical objects: for a tab bar, it's similar to having a file cabinet with the selected file (tab) shadowing the others, with the thicker line used as that "shadow". That said, yes, that could be the reason, and it could be a bug indeed. I'd suggest you to file a report on the [Qt bug tracker](//bugreports.qt.io) with precise info about OS/Qt versions.

Comment: It seems that adding `self.setDrawBase(False)` removes this. Thanks @musicamante for the discussion!